# Fetch on Push Failure?

Tags: email, ios

If the push service at an email server (like Office 365 for instance) fails or is not available for some reason, and you have your email settings set to Fetch Schedule `manual`, you will not get emails notifications; correct?

Comment: IMAP or POP? POP can't do push, it will only fetch when you open the mail app.

Comment: Office 365...and probably tls/ssl, I don't know what the underlying mail protocol is.

Comment: I have office365, it's on POP [idk whether it's capable of IMAP, but my own specific setup is POP only] therefore it will only fetch mail when you open the mail app inbox. The incoming mail server address used to be a dead giveaway - pop.outlook but mine recently changed to outlook.office365 which gives no real clue.